# Как задекорировать read-only метод класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, методы, декоратор, cx-oracle

### Описание проблемы

Есть модуль [cx-Oracle](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/). Я хотел задекорировать метод [execute](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.execute) класса [Cursor](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html), чтобы он логировал выполняемые запросы:

```py
import logging


class _QueryLogger:
    def __init__(self, execute_func):
        self._func = execute_func
        self._logger = logging.getLogger()

    def __call__(self, query: str):
        self._logger.log(level=logging.DEBUG, msg=query)
        return self._func(query)
```

Затем через контекстный менеджер возвращать объект курсора с задекорированным методом `execute`:

```py
import cx_Oracle
from credentials import credentials
from deco import _QueryLogger


class DbOracle:
    @contextmanager
    def _get_cursor(self):
        with cx_Oracle.Connection(**credentials) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute = _QueryLogger(cursor.execute)  # Проблема здесь
            yield cursor

    def execute(self, query):
        with self._get_cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
```

При пользовании этим:

```py
oracle = DbOracle()
oracle.execute("select * from v$version")
```

Возникает исключение:

```
AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only
```

### Вопрос

Как это можно обойти? Хотелось бы добавить логирование к самому объекту курсора, через который выполняются запросы.

### Зачем

В классе DbOracle предполагается несколько методов для выполнения различных SQL запросов. Прикрутить логирование к объекту курсора я хочу затем, чтобы в каждом из этих методов не логировать запрос перед тем, как его исполнить (читай, избежать дублирования кода).

Comment: Как вариант, объявить класс-наследник и переопределить один метод... А что, прям много много разных запросов в разных местах, что дублирование когда становится проблемой (просто интересно)? А еще же в самом SQL-сервере вдруг можно логгирование настроить (в postgresql так можно точно), главное временные отметки иметь, чтобы логи приложения и db-сервера склеить и можно анализировать любую сложившуюся ситуацию. Как мне кажется, не?

Comment: Определить класс-наследник идея хорошая, но как возвращать наследника, если `cursor = conn.cursor()` возвращает родителя? Логирование необходимо именно со стороны клиента.

Comment: В приведенном в вопросе классе `DbOracle` определен метод `def execute(self, query):` - почему бы туда логгирование не засунуть? В чем проблема? В самом коде уже повторена логика, о которой я намекаю, но не через наследование, а композицию, что где-то даже лучше. Осталось сделать маленький шаг. Сколько у вас таких `DbOracle`? Разве это не централизованный посредник для запуска запросов?

Comment: пишите прокси в который обернете cursor и логгируйте там все что требуется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В приведенном в вопросе классе `DbOracle` определен метод `def execute(self, query):` - почему бы туда логгирование не засунуть? © [mrEvgenX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/271103)

Это оказалось рациональным решением.